# Using Partial Fractions to Prove Aj = P(aj) / Q ' (aj)

Tags: integration

Here is my attempt at a solution for this problem; the problem is below.  I am really confused, dont know where to start.  Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = \sum \frac{A_i}{(x-a_i)}$.

First, multiply by $x-a_J$, for a fixed $J$, to get (all summations are over all possible $i$, unless specified otherwise):
$$
\frac{P(x)(x-a_J)}{Q(x)}  = \sum \frac{A_i(x-a_J)}{(x-a_i)} 
$$
Multiply by $Q$ on both sides:
$$
P(x)(x-a_J) = Q(x)\left( \sum \frac{A_i(x-a_J)}{(x-a_i)} \right)
$$
Now, differentiate:
$$
P'(x)(x-a_J) + P(x) = Q'(x)\left( \sum \frac{A_i(x-a_J)}{(x-a_i)} \right) +  Q(x)\left( \sum A_i\frac{(a_J-a_i)}{(x-a_i)^2} \right)
$$
We make one final simplification: just note that
$$
 \sum \frac{A_i(x-a_J)}{(x-a_i)} = A_J  + \sum_{i \neq J} \frac{A_i(x-a_J)}{(x-a_i)}
$$
Now, put $x=a_J$, and many of the terms involving $P'(x)$ and $Q(x)$ will completely vanish. Of the terms involving  $Q'(x)$, only one term will remain, namely $A_j$. Furthermore, since the $a_i$ are not repeated, only one $A_J$ will remain.
$$
P(a_J) = Q'(a_J)A_J
$$
In part  $B$, you can use this formula to find $A_j$ given $P$ and $Q$. That I leave to you.

Comment: Thanks, I will look this over.